# why cant i send discord messages with python requests anymore?

Tags: python, post, python-requests, discord

so i recently made this repl that can send discord messages using your token but it doesnt work anymore(i made it 2 days ago) and i dont know what happened(i think discord changed things that makes it not work but i could be wrong)and i really need help.
repl:https://replit.com/@coolgamermoth/Discord-message-sender
if you guys need any more information, ask me

also if u want the code, its here:

```
import requests

message = input("what you want to say-")
token = input("discord token-")
#the link can be found by getting from network or typing https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/<channel id>/messages
link = input("link-")
repeatvalue = input("how many times to repeat-")
interval = input("interval(in seconds)-")

payload = {
  'content': message
}

header = {
  'authorization': token, 'content-type': 'application/json'
}

from time import sleep

...

for i in range(int(repeatvalue)):
  res = requests.post(link, json=payload, headers=header)
  if res.ok:
    print(f'''\x1b[34msuccessfully sent "{message}" to server! ''')
  else:
    print(f'''\x1b[31munsuccessfully sent {message} to server... ''')
  sleep(float(interval))
```

i tried looking through the discord network to see if i had to add another header or something too, but it wasnt any different as far as i could tell

Comment: What is the exact error, if not the response code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre].

Comment: it just doesnt do anything except say: unsuccessfully sent {message} to server... which i made it say if it couldnt go through

Comment: "it just doesnt do anything except say: unsuccessfully sent {message} to server... which i made it say if it couldnt go through" - well, yes; that's because the only thing you actually check is whether `res.ok`. When something goes wrong, `res` will contain a lot more information. You should try writing code that examines this information, in order to understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certain this is a user agent issue. Change headers to as follows:

```py
header = {
  'authorization': token,
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
```